# PlayFramework - twirl function that returns boolean value?

Tags: playframework

Using PlayFramework, in my twirl template, given i have a function `canBeDone(List, List)`, how do i declare and use this function so it returns a boolean value?

The idea is I have some code

```
@if(canBeDone(list1, list2){
    ...
} ...
```

And declaring this like so (at the top of my twirl template):

```
@canBeDone(list1: List, list2:List) = { 
   ... 
}
```

But when I run this I get this error:

```
type mismatch; found : play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable (which expands to) play.twirl.api.Html required: Boolean
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Ah.

Turns out I need to declare a pure scala function - which means that I need to use a second "@" symbol.

So my code now looks like this (calling code is the same):

```
@canBeDone(list1: List, list2:List) = @{ 
    ... 
}
```

Notice that second "@" in the first line (right by the opening parenthesis?) ~ that makes the function a pure scala call. Using that I will get a bollean value back. Yay.